# Master silverlight application development code, xaml and all

Tags: silverlight

Assume a mechanic wants to start developing in silverlight and has managed to make a few sample childish applications.

What resources would you recommend to make him an expert?

Comment: One point resource for starting Silverlight
[Click Here](http://www.silverlight.net)

Comment: "Expert...." - *Do you have years to spare and no family/social life to miss*? Be careful what you wish for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking becoming an expert will involve years of training, lots of trial and error, and working on a large-scale applications always helps.  For some good resources, you might want to check out things like the Enterprise Library update for Silverlight which contains some good examples of architecture and scenarios you might encounter:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7319

Otherwise the Prism framework/guidance from Microsoft Patterns and Practices offers some information and examples on basic scenarios you might run into:

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

And lastly, stepping a bit outside of these examples you might want to try a book like Silverlight 4 Business Intelligence Software by Bart Czernicki.  It covers a lot of concepts for one type of SL scenario but the scope of the topics and exploration of concepts + framework is quite good:

[http://www.amazon.com/Silverlight-4-Business-Intelligence-Software/dp/1430230606/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1311760201&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230606)

You can also find a slew of experts on places like Twitter, try following someone like @Wynapse who does excellent daily coverage and can help you expand out to other experts in the area.